# Book Plot Sugestions

Tags: plot, fantasy, ideas

Does anyone have a good plot suggestion for a children's fantasy? Maybe about a 13 year old girl in the 1500's. Anything will do.

Comment: Hi, Lizzy. Unfortunately, this sort of open-ended plot question isn't really what we do here. There are lots of other sites where you could ask stuff like this, but we want questions to have a single focus and an objective answer.

Comment: Hi Lizzy.  As JSB said, this type of question isn't a good fit for this site, which is focused on answerable questions, not open-ended discussion.  However, if you build up a little reputation here (through asking or answering other questions, for example), you'll be able to use [chat], where free-flowing discussions and brainstorming are quite welcome.  I'm sorry we couldn't help you with this question, and I hope you'll stick around and check out other questions.

Comment: Perhaps this question could be 'rescued' by asking *where* one can find plot suggestions, particularly for that target audience and type of setting.

Comment: @Monica Cellio: Why are you referring to the poster as "Lizzy"?

Comment: @Rrr apparently the user has changed names since I left that comment in 2013.

Answer (score 3):

If I can suggest something, that would be a story about a young female who attends the medieval school of wizardry. She is forced to have very strict training and no friends in school, because teachers believe that one day, she will save the world and they don't want her to rely too much on others. Somehow, she fells in love with a boy, but later realizes that he is a vampire, and that her favorite teacher, who is secretly in love with her, is a werewolf too. Unfortunately, there are some bad wizards in the world, who take it over and start their totalitarian rules. Our hero has to take part (instead of her younger sister) in a deadly competition against other teens from the school, from which only one will survive. But in the grand finale, the army of animals comes to the rescue, with the great lion who becomes a new king of the magic kingdom.

I'd love to read a story like that.

Comment: You forgot the ninja exchange students who show up riding sharks.

Comment: The source material was better than the live-action Netflix adaptation  :(